# Partially exposed div to slide up when image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

this might be a weird one but what I am trying to do is make a div slide up from the bottom of the screen when someone clicks an image. To paint this clearer, imagine the Windows desktop, and if you click the start menu image/icon, instead of the start menu popping up from the button, the entire start menu bar would slide up exposing the entire div.

What I'm doing now (forgive me as I have just learned JS and jQuery from codecademy) is using the slideUp function. However, this is causing the div to slide down out of sight instead of up, exposing the entire div. The goal is that when you click the button the div slides up, and if you click the button again (or anywhere outside the div) it'll slide back down leaving the top 60px exposed like before.

**Here's my JS/jQuery code:**

```
$('#start').click(function() {
$('#nav').slideUp('slow');
});
```

**My HTML**

```
<div id="nav" class="nav">
    <img id="start" src="img/btn_start.png">
</div>
```

**My CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -440px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
 }

.nav ul li {
     display: inline;
}

 .nav li {
     padding: 20px;
     margin-top: 80px;
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
 }

 #start {
    float: left;
 }
```

Thanks, and I hope this isn't too ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `slideUp` you should use

```
$('#start').click(function() {   
    $('#nav').animate({bottom: "0px"}, 1200);   
});
```

...which will smoothly animate from the current location until the bottom is at 0px (i.e. aligned with the bottom of the containing element).

For even smoother results, checkout velocity.js (http://julian.com/research/velocity/), which does even smoother animation by synchronising with browser frame updates.

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/11r46jnm/

You can also do this with CSS transitions instead. For stuff like this I like to hook my CSS into data attributes on the HTML:

```
<div id="nav" class="nav" data-nav-state="collapsed">
    <img id="start" src="img/btn_start.png">
</div>
```

...use javascript to change the attributes...

```
$('#start').click(function() {
    //toggle the nav element between two states
    var currentState = $('#nav').attr("data-nav-state");
    var newState = "collapsed";
    if ( currentState === "collapsed" ) {
        newState = "expanded";
    } 
    $('#nav').attr("data-nav-state", newState);
});
```

Finally we use CSS to set the positions of the two states, and to ensure that transition is smooth. CSS transitions have much better performance than jQuery, so I recommend using them if you can:

```
 #nav[data-nav-state=collapsed] {
      bottom: -440px;
 }

 #nav[data-nav-state=expanded] {
      bottom: 0px;
 }

 #nav {
      transition: bottom 1.2s ease;
 }
```

See this jsFiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2saepy/1/

Comment: Awesome thank you @duncan, it works! What is the standard protocol to make the button reverse the effect? I figured out how to make it so where if you click outside the div it reverses the animation, but cannot figure out how to make the button do the same. I keep creating a conflict with the code you shared. And side question did my original way not work because .slideUp() (I now think) means slide the bottom of the div up until the div disappears?

Comment: If you're going to reverse the effect, you might want to consider CSS transitions instead - I'll add to my answer.

Comment: As for `slideUp()`, you've basically got it - it actually decreases the height of the element to zero, which only looks like a "slide up" if the top of the element is still, rather than the bottom. It's not a very good name!

Comment: ohh. So because I had that div with a position: absolute and bottom: 0px it caused it to look like it was sliding down. This all makes so much more sense. Thanks for your help! I will test out this CSS. I've never gotten too deep into experimental design so this has been an interesting project for me. Thank you!

Comment: and btw that jsfiddle was perfect! Did the job beautifully! Thanks!!